# Hbase browser showing Api Error: TSocket read 0 bytes in hue

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hue

I have installed Hue 3.8.1 on EC2 three node cluster. But while opening hbase browser on hue it is showing

> Api Error: TSocket read 0 bytes

Even Hbase thrift server is up and running in all three nodes… `thrift_transport=framed`… and `hbase.regionserver.thrift.server.type` is `TThreadPoolServer`… Could you please help to get out from this….

HBase version 1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258
hbase-thrift version -1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.el6.noarch

Comment: Have you tried 'thrift_transport=buffered'? Any info in the HBase Thrift Server logs?

Comment: I have tried thrift_transport=framed. I didn't see any error in Hbase logs.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue in cdh6.3.0.

After turn off `hbase.regionserver.thrift.compact` and `hbase.regionserver.thrift.framed` in HBase, the issue was fixed.